# Decoding circuit with transformer topology

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, schematics, rectifier

I am studying a circuit used for mobile adaptor, where AC to DC conversion is done through bridge rectifier ABS210. Transformer is used for isolation along with IC LP3783 (Offline PSR Driver) and LP3520 (Rectifier).

Circuit as below:

[image: Circuit]

I want to know which SMPS topology is used here?

Comment: Looks like the very common flyback converter to me, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter

Comment: The datasheet of the LP3783 hints the same: The device uses Pulse Frequency Modulation (PFM) method to build discontinuous conduction mode (DCM) **flyback power** supplies.

Comment: @Huisman , can you suggest why VCC of U1 is given from transformer? VCC is connected to primary or secondary side?

Comment: In order to supply the controller at start up. When started up, the winding connected to R5 and D2 takes it over. Vcc of U1 is connected to primary side by R1 and R2, and to (let's call it) tertiary side by R5 and D2. But not to the 'secondary' to which U2 is connected.

Comment: You can refer the following pdf from internet it contains details about various topologies used to design smps along with their applications. 01114a.pdf (part 1 of details of smps topologies) 01207b.pdf(part 2 of details of smps topologies)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why polarity of T1 is opposite where as application note has reverse polarity?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know which SMPS topology is used here ?

Almost certainly, it's a flyback topology. A big clue is the "opposite" dot-notation used on primary and secondary of the transformer. Dot notation polarity is very important for the correct operation of a flyback converter and the detail shown is typical of that type of design.

A 2nd clue is in the data sheet details - they give more example circuits and they all look like flyback designs to me: -

[image]

Comment: Another big clue is the reversed polarity diode across the transformer primary. It rules out all non-flyback topologies.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why polarity of T1 is opposite where as application note has reverse polarity?

Comment: @Techknowlogic I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Notch at primary is down in image where as in conventional flyback converter it is at top at primary and down at output winding side.

Comment: @Techknowlogic it is the relative position of the dots that is important. Any single winding (on its own) can be used in either polarity but, when used in a flyback design, and considering primary and secondary, the dots need to be at at opposing ends as shown. This then achieves the correct polarity of voltages for primary and secondary.

Comment: @ Andy aka , Thanks for answer. There are 3 windings used here in flyback design and typical flyback converter has 2 windings which I have gone through in all flyback design application notes.  My question is where I can find information of 3 winding transformer and its theory/design.

Comment: The third winding isn't always needed but in the circuits above it does two things: (1) feedback of the output voltage to maintain closed loop control (yes it's indirect but it works to within +/- 5%) and (2) can provide supplementary power to the "chip" when starting from cold. In both circuits it achieves both those functions.

Comment: Can you suggest Texas equivalent IC or design guide for such transformer design. Thanks for your help for my understanding.

Comment: I can't sorry. It's all in my head and I'd probably not use a Texas part because I don't find their support documentation as good as others.

Comment: Ok any other manufacturers equivalent part then.

Comment: I would consider these guys: https://ac-dc.power.com/ but the precise choice is totally dependent on many factors. I would also go to premier magnetics to see what transformers they offer for the simple reason that they can supply the transformer and provide circuit diagrams using TI, Fairchild and power integrations parts: http://www.premiermag.com/pdf/POL.pdf